# Why does Cassian think the Guardians of the Whills are just causing trouble for everybody?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

> "Who are they?"
>
> "The Guardians of the Whills. Protectors of the Temple of the Kyber.
>   But there's nothing left to protect, so now they're just causing
>   trouble for everybody."
>
> ― Jyn Erso and Captain Cassian Jeron Andor

The Guardians' priority is to resist the Empire and protect the people of Jedha.

Why would a rebel captain think otherwise?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is addressed in the novelisation which contains a few extra lines of dialogue. In short, the Guardians are zealots. Although their cause is roughly aligned with the Rebellion, they're unreliable and likely to bring down Imperial attention.

> *She frowned. “What kind of trouble?”*
>
> *Cassian turned his head in a slow arc as if checking for pursuit. “For
> the Guardians, anyone who’s not a pilgrim is intruding on holy ground.
> The Empire calls them strays…used to be domesticated, still beg for
> scraps, but they’ve really gone feral. Look at them wrong and they’ll
> bite your hand in a second.” “You’ll make me like them,” Jyn said.*
>
> *She tried to push their faces, Chirrut’s voice, out of her brain. They
> probably were con men, even if they’d been zealots once. Beyond that,
> she didn’t know enough about the local religions to speculate;
> pilgrims from a hundred faiths came to the moon from across the
> galaxy, and all of them blurred together into the same pathetic cult,
> chanting and moaning and squirming under the Empire’s boot.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: A Star Wars Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story_(novel))</sup></sub>

Comment: In the movie they actually don't look feral at all.

Comment: @KinzleB - Baze looks a bit feral :-)

Comment: The actor who plays Baze is very famous in China. He has played lots of good guys. That's why our peers would not think of him as a villain. :)

Comment: I'll let you in on a little secret. The reason why the two actors who play Baze and Chirrut accepted the roles is that their kids are big fans of Star Wars. They urged their fathers to take part in it. :)

Comment: No. Actually, they were invited to play in some other movies in China back then. Money was no big concern for them. They have earned their fame and fortune in China for quite a time. :)

Comment: @KinzleB - That just makes me double bummed [spoiler] they both were killed[/spoiler]. Those two for my money were easily the best characters in the movie. They could probably have been edited out with no real impact, but they made every scene they were in much better.

Comment: @T.E.D. your spoiler doesn't work ;)